# How to exclude specific values from two different tables in a SELECT Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables lets say 'Begin'& 'End' with five columns each.
Begin contains Id, T1, T2, T3, T4. End contains Id, T1E, T2E, T3E, T4E. When i run the query to select everything from two tables by joining them, I get a result. but the problem is, in the result there are some rows where I get all T1, T2, T3, T4, T1E, T2E, T3E, T4E 0. i am trying to exclude the columns where all the values are zero.

Please help me exclude the values where T1, T2, T3, T4, T1E, T2E, T3E, T4E = 0

Thank you

Comment: where abs(t1) + abs(t1e) ... + abs(t4e) <> 0

Comment: post your attempt, some sample data

Comment: is it possible for any of the numbers to be negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE NOT (T1=0 AND T2=0 AND T3=0 AND T4=0 AND T1E=0 AND T2E=0 AND T3E=0 AND T4E=0)
```

Comment: Same as `where (t1 <> 0 OR t1e <> 0 ... OR t4e <> 0)`.

Comment: thank you so much, It worked. i will get back to this post If I Have any further  issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can make sure everything is not equal to 0:

```
SELECT ... FROM TA
INNER JOIN TAE ON ...
WHERE T1 <> 0 
    OR T2 <> 0 
    OR T3 <> 0 
    OR T4 <> 0 
    OR T1E <> 0 
    OR T2E <> 0 
    OR T3E <> 0 
    OR T4E <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VALUES` so as to construct an in-line table consisting of all to-be-examined fields. Then perform a `COUNT` on this table to find if *all* fields are equal to `0`:

```
SELECT b.*, e.*
FROM [Begin] AS b
INNER JOIN [End] AS e ON b.Id = e.Id
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (VALUES (b.T1), (b.T2), (b.T3), (b.T4),
               (e.T1E), (e.T2E), (e.T3E), (e.T4E)) x(v)
  WHERE x.v = 0) t(cnt)
WHERE t.cnt < 8
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e752/2)

Answer (score 0):

If negative values are not possible, you can just add them:

```
WHERE T1 + T2 + T3 + T4 + T1E + T2E + T3E + T4E > 0
```